# How to set font style on the first item of a QComboBox?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I would to set the font style of first item on a QComboBox.
I'm using the Qt framework.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
combo.setItemData(rowIndex, QVariant(myCustomFont), Qt.FontRole)
```

I'm using PyQt